# jQuery hover on div excludes image

Tags: jquery, hover

I placed a hover animation on a div like so:

```
$('#divID').hover(function(){
$('#divID').animate({'margin-top': '-200px'}, 200);
});
```

This all works fine,
but when I place an image inside that div, and I hover on that image instead of the div's free space the function doesn't trigger, because the image is another object.

I want the function to trigger regardless of the content of the div.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you produce a jsFiddle example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/D9mWm/1/

It is working fine for me.

Comment: Here is the jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/KoenvE/LFrKN/

It works, but when you hover the image, the behaviour is really weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Nailed it: the behaviour is correct since you are actually leaving the div. Dont apply the event to the children and [**youre good to go**](http://jsfiddle.net/LFrKN/2/):

```
$('#google').not($('#google').children()).mouseleave(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#google').stop().animate({'margin-top': '0px'}, 200);
});
```

---

Well basically this should not happen. You can try to use a direct `mouseenter` event instead of `hover`, but hover does use mouseenter anyways.
To me it seems there is another problem.

Try something like this:

```
$('#divID').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#divID').stop().animate({'margin-top': '-200px'}, 200);
});
```

Comment: As you already wrote; hover implements both mouseenter and mouseout so there shouldn't be any difference.

Answer (score -1):

instead of just hover event you should use mouseout event as well. so now your script will be:

```
 $('#mostread').hover(function(){
$('#mostread').animate({'margin-top': '-200px'}, 200);

});

 $('#mostread').mouseout(function(){
$('#mostread').animate({'margin-top': '+200px'}, 200);
});
```

Comment: this makes no sense. $().hover(func1, func2); uses nothing else than mouseleave. so either use .hover() with 2 functions or use mouseenter and mouseleave accordingly. also, this was not the question the author had..